# Which function resize images with better quality, imagecopyresampled() or imagescale()?

Tags: php, image, resize

I want to make image smaller than original with PHP. I tried imagecopyresampled() and imagescale(), it looks like imagescale() makes slightly better quality of image. But some images resized with imagescale() has worse quality than imagecopyresampled(). What are your experiences with these functions? Is there a better way to resize image with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on what image you're resizing, there's no way of knowing what will get a better quality image, as that's very subjective if you use image scale you can use the $mode argument to choose how the image will be scaled, this is one of `IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR, IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED, IMG_BICUBIC, IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED`, it will give you a finer control on the scaling